# How with setting up Polish characters using POI

Tags: apache-poi

I have to convert Document from docx to pdf. Conversion coming out correctly but i can't see polish characters. Anyone had this problem?

My code :

```
String inputChangeFile = "wniosekzaciagniecie.docx";
InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
length = inputChangeFile.length();
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputstream);            
PdfOptions options =PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("windows-1250");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("kakaowyszal.pdf"));
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your polish characters can be represented in the `windows-1250` character set?

Comment: I don't know, but probably yes.